# Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException on zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I followed this guide https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os and have an error poping up on the step wihere I run consumer from cmd  with en infinite loop of such line in zookeeper. I tried to reinstall everything from 0 but didnt help either

```
2017-09-21 18:11:25,990 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2017-09-21 18:11:34,001 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@358] - Expiring session 0x15ea52a6e0a0001, timeout of 6000ms exceeded
2017-09-21 18:11:34,005 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@486] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15ea52a6e0a0001
2017-09-21 18:11:34,007 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@203] - Creating new log file: log.e3
2017-09-21 18:12:09,218 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51360
2017-09-21 18:12:09,224 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@942] - Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51360
2017-09-21 18:12:09,232 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@687] - Established session 0x15ea53547c80000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51360
2017-09-21 18:12:09,541 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@486] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15ea53547c80000
2017-09-21 18:12:09,547 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51360 which had sessionid 0x15ea53547c80000
2017-09-21 18:12:47,480 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:61769
2017-09-21 18:12:47,491 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@942] - Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:61769
2017-09-21 18:12:47,496 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@687] - Established session 0x15ea53547c80001 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /127.0.0.1:61769
2017-09-21 18:12:48,149 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@648] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15ea53547c80001 type:create cxid:0x3e zxid:0xea txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers
2017-09-21 18:12:48,150 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@648] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15ea53547c80001 type:create cxid:0x3f zxid:0xeb txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids
2017-09-21 18:12:48,173 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@648] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15ea53547c80001 type:delete cxid:0x44 zxid:0xed txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election
2017-09-21 18:13:09,484 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56612
2017-09-21 18:13:09,515 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException
2017-09-21 18:13:09,516 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56612 (no session established for client)
2017-09-21 18:13:09,572 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56613
2017-09-21 18:13:09,575 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException
2017-09-21 18:13:09,576 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56613 (no session established for client)
2017-09-21 18:13:09,682 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56614
2017-09-21 18:13:09,683 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException
2017-09-21 18:13:09,683 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56614 (no session established for client)
2017-09-21 18:13:09,787 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56615
```

Comment: Any luck fixing this? I'm having this exact same issue.